# String index out of range: -1; substring issue

Tags: java, string, exception

I'm writing a program for class which counts words in a string and, if the inputted string has more than 3 words, prints the sentence again, but with each word on its own line.

So I'm trying to replace spaces with `\n`. When I input a sentence that has more than 3 words, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
        at lab3.main(lab3.java:32)
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab3 {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    int wordCount = 1;
    char aChar;

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence.");

    String sentence = scan.nextLine();
    int charCount = sentence.length();

    for (int i=0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
            if (sentence.charAt(i) != ' '){

                    continue;
            } else {
                    wordCount++;
                    }
            }

    System.out.println("Number of words = " + wordCount);

            if (wordCount >= 4){
            for (int i = 0; i <= charCount; i++){
                    int space = sentence.indexOf(" ");
                    int endSpace = space + 1;
                    sentence = sentence.substring(0, space) 
                            + "\n"
                            + sentence.substring(endSpace, sentence.length());
                    }
                    System.out.println(sentence);

            } else {
            System.out.println(sentence);

            }

    }
}
```

The problem seems to be coming from the for loop at line 31, but I don't understand how it's returning -1 when I input a sentence longer than 3 words. Am I using substring wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Myself, I'd use `String#split(...)` method and would be able to solve this in just a few lines of code.

Comment: `sentence.indexOf()` will return `-1` if `" "` is not found and `space` is passed into `sentence.substring()`: check `space`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your code then you would have to do a check when doing **sentence.index(" ")** if it return -1. if it returns you breakout of the loop as below.
however, this isnt a good style of coding. i'd rather do with regex or other simpler methods from String API.

```
 if (wordCount >= 4){
            for (int i = 0; i <charCount-3; i++){
                    int space = sentence.indexOf(" ");
                    if(space==-1){// check if space is -1
                        break;
                    }   
                    System.out.println(i+ " " + space);
                    int endSpace = space + 1;
                    sentence = sentence.substring(0, space)
                            + "\n"
                         + sentence.substring(endSpace, sentence.length()-1);
                    }
                    System.out.println(sentence);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that the index of `space` here. `String.indexOf()` will return `-1` if the search string is not found.

```
int space = sentence.indexOf(" ");
int endSpace = space + 1;
if (space != -1) {
    sentence = sentence.substring(0, space) + "\n"
            + sentence.substring(endSpace, sentence.length());
}
```

Comment: For clarification, `indexOf()` will return -1 if it can not find the string.

Comment: Thanks guys! I guess it's a little late to ask, but is there anything wrong with the way I posted this? I understand I should've pointed out the line I was referring to..

Comment: Ideally yes its good to point out the line that the app fails on but you did post a [sccee](http://sscce.org/) which helps a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Myself, I'd use `String#split(...)` method and would be able to solve this in just a few lines of code.
- But if you must do it this way, don't do a `for` loop or loop charCount number of times since charCount is the size of the String and you certainly don't want to loop this many times. It just doesn't make sense. Rather, you want to loop the number of spaces, not the number of characters, which brings me to the next recommendation:
- Use a `while` loop, not a `for` loop and loop until -1 is returned by the `indexOf(...)` method. In other words, let Java do the hard work of figuring out when the String has run out of spaces rather than you guess.

Answer (score 0):

My solution does not check for words that are not actually words,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SentenceWordCount {
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    int wordCount;

    public SentenceWordCount() {
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");

        String sentenceEntered = s.nextLine();
        String[] brokenSentence = sentenceEntered.split(" ");

        wordCount = brokenSentence.length;

        if(wordCount > 3){
        for(String s : brokenSentence){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Number of words equals : " + wordCount);
    }
}
```

Cheers,

Jamie